# How to bind a hotkey to a class method in AutoHotkey

Tags: autohotkey

In AutoHotkey (1.1.29.01), how can I dynamically bind a hotkey to a class method?

```
class MyClass
{
    SayHi()
    {
        MsgBox Hi!
    }

    BindHotkey()
    {
        Hotkey, Enter, this.SayHi, On
    }
}
```

Error:

> Target label does not exist

Answer (score 5):

Call `Bind` on the function, passing `this`, and store the result in a variable. Then pass the variable to `Hotkey`.

```
class MyClass
{
    SayHi()
    {
        MsgBox Hi!
    }

    BindHotkey()
    {
        SayHiFunc := this.SayHi.Bind(this)

        Hotkey, Enter, % SayHiFunc, On
    }
}
```